# spring boot eclipse link security exception

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, eclipselink

I'm using spring boot `v1.2.3` with embedded tomcat7. In the `build.gradle` I have dependencies:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
runtime 'org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.5.2'
```

In addition, I have a legacy dependency on a jar that is using eclipse persistence `v1.1.4`.

At runtime,the following exception occurs:

```
Cause: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceInitializationHelper"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

Is there anyway to get around this without updating the eclipse.persistence in the legacy code?